# What is the problem with my systemd script?

Tags: bash, xubuntu, systemd

It works fine, but the notify-send is put "backwards" before other notifications, here's: an image:

[image: picture]

It feels like my notification is in a different "group" or something...

The notification should come AFTER the mullvad notification.

service script:

```
[Unit]
Description=Turns off microphone at startup
#After=multi-user.target
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/bin/microphone-status
User=tom
RemainAfterExit=yes
Environment="DISPLAY=:0.0" "XAUTHORITY=/home/tom/.Xauthority"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10
#/usr/bin/update-notifier
/usr/bin/notify-send -u normal 'Why does it appear on top?'
#function check_state () {
#   toggle_toggle=$(/usr/bin/amixer get Capture | grep -c "\[off\]")
#   echo toggle+percent
#   toggle_percent=$(/usr/bin/amixer get Capture | grep -c "\[0%\]")
#   echo toggle_percent
#   let toggle_result=$((toggle_toggle+toggle_percent))
#   echo $((toggle_result))
#}
#check_state
#/usr/bin/notify-send -u normal $toggle_result # IF 4  = TURNED OFF, IF !=4 TURNED ON

#if [ $(/usr/bin/pgrep pavucontrol) > 0 ] ; then  # Check if pavucontrol has processID = active
#echo "found pavucontrol"
#   if [ $((toggle_result)) != 4 ] ; then # Turn off microphone once
#       toggle off
#           /usr/bin/killall -9 xfce4-notifyd
#           /usr/bin/notify-send 'Microphone was left turned on' 'It was automatically disabled.'
#       /usr/bin/amixer set Capture toggle
#           /usr/bin/amixer set Capture 0
#           /usr/bin/amixer set Capture 0%
#   fi
#fi

exit 0
```

Another picture - the notification starts at a really weird place - at half at my taskbar

[image: Why is my service's notification at such a weird place?]

Comment: We'll also need to see /opt/bin/microphone-status as well - SystemD is *designed* to execute at boot not at user login, so any "notifications" may be delayed, and if you have multiple notification systems going at the same time they have different priorities in where they show up

Comment: @ThomasWard there you go

Comment: @ThomasWard then i need to find a service that starts when everything is ready in the dekstop, right?

Comment: it SOUNDS more like you want a startup application, not a SystemD service, that starts after your login starts.  Which is less a SystemD service but having yoru script run in Startup Applications.  Like https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html.en details

Comment: @ThomasWard I need a service. Every single google result comes up with creating a service if i want to start a script on startup. And even if i don't need a service, i want one. So how do i move on forward?

Comment: There's a difference between script at system startup and script at USER startup.  Anything that requires a notification being sent to a GUI frontend fits within the Userspace startup not the System startup.  If you *want* to make your script simply be a service, have it do its stuff and log to syslog instead, rather than doing a GUI notification.  GUI notifications won't work right with a SystemD service because of race conditions, etc. and don't operate the same as GNOME-driven notifications.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117654/discussion-between-thomas-ward-and-john-dale).

Answer (score 0):

cat /lib/systemd/system/alsa-volume-default.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Alsa volume default servivce.
 After=alsa-restore.service
PartOf=alsa-restore.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/bin/alsa-controls.sh init

[Install]
WantedBy=alsa-restore.service
```

cat /home/bac0n/.config/autostart/alsa-controls.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Alsa volume notify
Exec=/bin/bash -c "/opt/bin/alsa-controls.sh check; sudo -n /opt/bin/alsa-controls.sh reset"
GenericName=Alsa Volume Notify
Name=AlsaControls
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

cat /etc/sudoers.d/alsa-controls

```
Cmnd_Alias CMDS = /opt/bin/alsa-controls.sh reset
User_Alias CMDUSERS = bac0n
CMDUSERS ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: CMDS
Defaults!CMDS env_keep += DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

cat /opt/bin/alsa-controls.sh

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

file=/var/lib/alsa-controls/state

# alsa-volume-default.service
init(){
    local left right state

    read -d '' -r left right < <( \
    amixer sget DAC,0 | \
    sed -nr 's/Front .* \[([0-9]+)%\]$/\1/p')

    mkdir -p ${file%/*} || exit 1

    # 0 = unchanged, 1 = changed
    [[ $left -eq $right \
    && $left -eq 5 ]]; state=$?
    amixer -q sset DAC,0 5% && echo $state > $file
}

# Autostart as unprivileged.
check(){
    read -r -N 1 < $file || exit
    [[ $REPLY = +([1-9]) ]] && \
    notify-send -t 0 -u normal "alsa notify" "Alsa volume has been altered."
}

# Autostart as root (sudo).
reset(){
    [[ $EUID -eq 0 ]] \
    && echo 0 > $file
}

[[ $1 = @(init|check|reset) ]] && $1

exit 0
```

Comment: Description is on the way...